# Symfony2 - Session timeout

Tags: php, symfony, session-timeout

First of all, I've been looking around for informations about this but it was all about Symfony 1.x or even more confusing...

#### Environment

- Symfony 2.3
- FOSUserBundle + Custom User entity

#### Problem

In the web site I'm developing I would like user session to end (= have to log in again) either when they close their browser or after 2 hours.

In the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session%20%22Symfony2%20documentation) they say that the default timeout is set with the parameter "framework.session.cookie_lifetime" of the config.yml, and that its default value is 0 which means that the session expires when the user closes his browser.

Those options are still on default in my configuration file, but when I a open a session and then close the browser, if I reopen it and go to the website I'm still logged in... So that's where I started getting confused... I tried to force the cookie_lifetime value to 0, but it's the same.

The config.yml with the cookie_lifetime option setted :

```
framework:
    translator: {fallback: %locale%}
    secret: %secret%
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
      cookie_lifetime: 0
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
```

Do you have any idea why this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually browsers don't end a session if you keep the tab open — even if you restart the browser.

Comment: You mean that if there is only one tab open in my browser and I close the browser, it won't end the session ?

What if I have multiple tabs open and I juste close the one with my web site. Is it supposed to end the session ?

Comment: Depends on the browser and whether it reopens tabs from the previous session when you restart it.

Comment: Well I tried several conditions in Firefox and the session is never ended. Closing the tab and browser works on Chrome though.
I don't like when things are not regular...

Comment: As you can see, it's browser specific. I wouldn't bother with this. I'd set the session cookie config to default and set up the [Remember Me feature](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) to remember the user for 2 hours.

Comment: Hi again, I tried to set the remember me like on the link you provided but it doesn't work. When I log in I can see the REMEMBERME cookie in the browser options and it is set to now + 2hours (and the PHPSESSID is still there with 'session lifetime') but if I close the browser and come back to the website, I'm not logged anymore.

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem. Did you have any luck solving this?